# Unable to launch com.myappname on iPhone through Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

When, I'm trying to launch my app on real device iPhone, I'm getting an error: "Unable to launch com.myappname":

[image]

also I noticed weird behavior, when running app on simulator, instead of running app immediately, Xcode first shows me such window:

[image]

If this app wasn't installed in simulator before, I can't run it now. What can be wrong? and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, I went to `Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme` and there was "`Executable Ask on Launch`", I changed `Ask on Launch` to my app name and now it works as expected!

[image]